# How to find nth parent of an element using jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, navigation, parent

I want to find the nth parent element of an given element and access the attributes of parent.

```
<div id='parent1'><br/>
  <div id='parent2'><br/>
       <span><p id='element1'>Test</p></span><br/>
  </div><br/>
  <div id='parent3'><br/>
       <span><p id='element2'>Test</p></span><br/>
  </div><br/>
</div>
```

I want to access the 3rd parent element of element1 without using

```
$('#element1').parent().parent().parent()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the n-th level parent of an element in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093659/how-do-i-get-the-n-th-level-parent-of-an-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use `.parents()` and `.eq()`:

```
$('#element1').parents().eq(2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/4YmYt/

Answer (score 8):

use:

```
$('#element1').closest('#parent1');
```

Comment: If you know the ID there wouldn't be any point in using `closest`

Comment: thanks. this code is good enough for the current example.But i want to search it dynamically like 3rd parent or 4th parent

Comment: @Richard Dalton, how about $('#element1').closest('#parent1').hasClass('whatever');

Answer (score 8):

[parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) returns a list, so this works:

```
$('#element1').parents()[2];
```

Answer (score 6):

You could make a little plugin to take care of that:

```
$.fn.nthParent = function(n){
    var p = this;
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
        p = p.parent();
    return p;
}
```

and then use it as:

```
$('#element1').nthParent(3);
```