# moving steps up in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to move steps up in the DOM through JQuery or Javascript? (preferably JQuery)

To avoid doing a sequence of `parent()` tags, I should better use something that could sum something like this up:

```
$('.myElement').parent().parent().parent().fadeIn();
```

This should target the `.final` element in the following example:

```
<div class="final">
    <div>
       <div>
          <div class="myElement"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no .final element

Comment: Your snippet does not include a `.final` element. But, assuming it's in the actual markup, try [`.closest('.final')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: Use a selector for whatever parent you want to get. For instance if the top div is in the body you can do `$('.myElement').parent('body div').fadeIn()`;

Comment: you can refer to this solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093659/how-do-i-get-the-n-th-level-parent-of-an-element-in-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between jQuery parent() and closest() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193212/difference-between-jquery-parent-and-closest-function)

Comment: `$('.myElement').closest('.final').fadeIn();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `.parents()` is for. To get the N+1th parent, do:

`$(this).parents()[N])`

For example, `$(this).parents()[0]` is the first parent.

Comment: so what should .final's number in parents() should it increment like an array? [0] standing for the first parent?

Comment: `.final`'s number should be `[2]`, since it's the third in the list of parents.

Comment: You can replace N calls to `.parent()` with `.parents()[N-1]`.

Comment: I had already tried the closest() tag, but it doesnt work, don't know why

Comment: @GEspinha, note that `parents` can easily break when you update and mutate the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `.final` is a ancestor element of the `.myElement` element, you can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$('.myElement').closest('.final').fadeIn();
```